# Android debug HTTP request console

Tags: android, eclipse, http, console

When I run my app from eclipse with "Run as Android application" , It is running well. I am running it in my nexus device with USB debugging. The app is calling some web services with some HTTP requests . But I don't see the requests in console. I want to see the response of requests. How to do this. ?

Comment: I think you need to write your own logs.
and see the logs in LogCat view in eclipse